# Behaviour of assign_attributes with nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variable-assignment, nested-forms

assign_attributes doesn't seem to recognise when I delete nested objects.

I have a model called Order:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :deliveries, :dependent => :destroy             
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :deliveries, :allow_destroy => true

end
```

Say I create an order with two deliveries. Then I open the 'edit order' form (which is a nested form where you can see the two nested deliveries), and then delete one of the deliveries, i.e. so that the '_destroy' attribute is set to true.

Then, if I do:

```
@order = Order.find_by_id(params[:id])
@order.assign_attributes(order_params)
logger.debug "@order.deliveries: #{@order.deliveries.inspect}"
```

I can see that both of the deliveries are still there nested under the order.

However, if I do

```
@order = Order.find_by_id(params[:id])
@order.update_attributes!(order_params)
logger.debug "@order.deliveries: #{@order.deliveries.inspect}"
```

One of the deliveries is deleted as expected.

Is this expected behaviour by assign_attributes? Ideally I'd like it to remove the delivery that has been deleted, but not save the resulting objects/links to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`accepts_nested_attributes_for` handles deletes through a callback. The child records won't go away until you save the parent (which `update_attributes` does).

If you dig through the code for `accepts_nested_attributes_for` you can find where it stores the list of records to be deleted.